# Batch Script loop recursively on directories, appending inital directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following batch script

```
for /D /r %%f in ( %~dp0 ) do echo %%f
```

which should, as I understand it, Loop over all directories recusively in the directory storing the batch script, and print the full file path....

However, if the batch script is located in "C:\my\path" and under it there are folders "a", "a\b" and "a\b\c" I get the following output

```
C:\my\path\a\C:\my\path
C:\my\path\a\b\C:\my\path
C:\my\path\a\b\c\C:\my\path
```

What is wrong with this script?

Comment: That is because `for` does not access the file system to resolve the set in between the parentheses if there is no wildcard (`*`, `?`) in it, so the string is returned literally...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to miss-use the for command:

```
for /D /r %~dp0 %%F in ( *.* ) do echo %%~F
```

The syntax for `/R` is:

```
FOR /R [[drive:]path] %%parameter IN (set) DO command
```

See http://ss64.com/nt/for.html

Answer (score 1):

Change your command thus to use the current directory.

```
FOR /D /R %%a IN (*) DO ECHO=%%a
```

Change your command thus to use the script directory.

```
FOR /D /R "%~dp0" %%a IN (*) DO ECHO=%%a
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because `for` does not access the file system to resolve the set in between the parentheses if there is no wildcard (`*`, `?`) in it, so the string is returned literally.

Nevertheless, the file system is of course accessed to enumerate the directory tree given after `/R`.

Provide the root path for `for /R` after the switch `/R` and use global wildcards in the set. To search for directories rather than files, use the `/D` switch:

```
for /D /R "%~dp0" %%F in ("*.*") do echo %%~F
```

Do not forget to put quotation marks around path items to avoid trouble with whitespaces and other special characters. The `~` modifier of the `for` variable removes them in the loop body.

---

Alternatively, to return a pure directory list without any filtering, you can use the set `.`, like this:

```
for /R "%~dp0" %%F in (.) do echo %%~F
```

The output might look like this:

> ```
> C:\my\path\a\.
> C:\my\path\a\b\.
> C:\my\path\a\b\c\.
> ```

Comment: None of this had any relevance to the fact they are doing a directory search!

Comment: @Compo, Actually what aschipfl points is the reason of the behaviour indicated in the OP question and the answer to the original *`What is wrong with this script?`*. `for` command does two different kind of searchs: `/r` enumerate folders from the indicated or default starting point, but the `set` clause **with wildcards** will enumerate matching files. Without a wildcard, the contents in the `set` clause are simply appended to the result of the `/r` search.

Comment: The OP had an issue because they've put the %~dp0 in the wrong place when hoping to do a directory search rooted in the script location directory. (That was cleared up in my previous answer) Additionally the information about the /r switch etc. was cleared up in the other existing answer by MrTux.

Comment: @Compo, MCND got what I was trying to say; the solution is (almost) the same as the other answers, but none of them explained why the original code behaves like it does; that is why I decided to provide an answer; there is no reason for down-voting in my opinion; I will update my answer to clarify...

Comment: Your updated `for /D` answer still uses an unnecessarily extended version of what I posted which was a slightly shorter corrected version of MrTux' response. Your non **/D** option which matches the content of the `For /?` documentation method actually outputs a non wanted trailing backspace and dot. It doesn't add anything but confusion to a simple question which had already been answered adequately by two respondents.

Comment: But none of the other answers explains *why* the original code did not return the desired output, @Compo; concerning the alternative method: the additional suffix `\.` does not disturb technically as paths like `C:\dir\.\something` and `C:\dir\something` are totally equivalent, so it is only a cosmetic issue...

Comment: I know it does not disturb the path, it just echoes it wrongly. The OP was getting 'the initial directory appended' **which was the question**

Comment: They even commented on the answer by MrTux  because the fix was that they had placed %~dp0 inside the parentheses which was therefore appended. My response only came to correct the double quotes and explain the often missed difference between current and script directories to finalise the question

Comment: @Compo, it seems that you have a different sense of "finalising the question"; if I would have asked the question, I would prefer answers that explain *why* something is behaving unexpectedly; anyway, our opinions seem not to match, but I totally accept that -- full stop.